# Why is the Samsung Galaxy A20e not compatible with my Unity app?

Tags: arcore

We' ve got an app out for open testing but my client can't run it on her Galaxy A20 (says 'device not compatible with this version'). She has installed Google Play Services on her device also.

On my dev console the A20 is not shown on the supported device list, although surely it's ARCore compatible (2019 device).?

Can anybody help me understand how to fix this?

Using Unity 2020.3.8f1, ARCore 4.1.7. Min Api level set to 24. Il2cpp backend for 64-bit device support.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I’m having the exact same problem with my client. Have you figured it out?